# Using Google Maps API to selectively highlight railway routes one at a time?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, transit

I am trying to understand the TransitLayer in Google Maps' Javascript API. Utilizing Google's example code, I managed to display a geographically-accurate map of Tokyo Metro, Toei Subway and Yokohama Municipal Subway routes here: https://jsfiddle.net/dsd00wb0/

But what I want to do is highlight specific lines one at a time. For instance, only highlight the Asakusa Line. I can do that in [Google Maps](https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/Oshiage+Station,+Japan/Nishi-Magome+Station,+2+Chome-1-6+Nishimagome,+Ota,+Tokyo+143-0026,+Japan/@35.6490311,139.6894773,12z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x60188ed63c424369:0xa16dd866dfaa5fb9!2m2!1d139.812428!2d35.71021!1m5!1m1!1s0x6018601de72fd04f:0x9bbedc1b1a4182c4!2m2!1d139.7061037!2d35.5874103!3e3), but what I want to know is if I can specifically do it using the Google Maps API.

Moreover, how would you highlight heavy rail/overland lines like the Yamanote Line? The TransitLayer only works on subway lines.

I have been able to extract route relations for specific railway lines in OpenStreetMap (using JOSM), but Google Maps is a lot more confusing.

Comment: Try using the Transit side of MapTypeStyleFeatureType https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple for your rail lines

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you mean use MapTypeStyleFeatureType object to display heavy rail/overland lines (e.g. Yamanote Line, Keikyu Line), or that I can use the MapTypeStyleFeatureType object to display one subway line at a time?